# Unable to import/require ES module from common JS

Tags: import, electron, require, commonjs

I'm using electron to build a UI for a specific project, the problem is that I wrote the core code in ES while apparently ES breaks electron.

What I am trying to do is to export some callback functions from HID.js to my electron app

HID.js

```
export {setKeycode, getLayerKeycodes, getKeycode, findConnectedDevices};
```

index.js

```
const {setKeycode, getLayerKeycodes, getKeycode, findConnectedDevices} = require('../../core/HID.js');
```

this leads to the expected result of "error: require() of ES module"

the problem is that if I try to import it, I will have to change the electron application to be a "module" and for some reason ES breaks the entire electron library, so it won't be possible.

How can I import those functions without breaking electron?

Comment: Electron does not implement all features of ESM in particular import/export statements. You need to transpile them with tools like babel.

Answer (score 0):

like @darkomen mentioned, it is possible to transpile the wanted module before running electron, and then import the transpiled file instead. However, I found it much easier to just change the original code to cms as it can get out of hand. If you really want to use the babel method:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

then, in the same folder open a file named babelrc.json and type this in:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

create those scripts - change index.js to the file you want to transpile, remember to change the "software" folder to the one you need as well. When the build script runs it will open a dist folder (if it doesn't exist already) and saves the transpiled file there.

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel index.js -d dist",
    "start": "npm run build && electon ../software/src"
  }
```

Now, instead of importing the normal index.js import the one that is in dist. The start script will transpile index every time that you run it.

It took a long time to figure out how to do it, and it indeed worked but it requires changing some of the paths because the files are now in a new folder. It also created many other issues, so if you have the option just change your code to commonjs - it is the easier solution.